# Python 2.7 import lib from folder lib

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im have project with next strucure

```
lib
 -gloud
 -oauth2client
  ..........
main.py
```

How i can import libraries from folder lib?
in main.py im write

```
imoprt gcloud
```

but it's error

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `from lib import gcloud`, because it's inside a folder and python imports work like this.

Or simply use `import lib.gcloud`. Is it a good way though? Isn't there any package available from pip?

Comment: im try doing google app engine application and im put all lib in folder "lib"
it is good practicals? usual im imoprt lib from repositories using pip

Comment: I meant it this way: these kind of libraries seems to have really important updates(I saw "oauth" and I think it has something to do with google drive), so using your own copy instead of a package that is in some kind of repository where you can access it better way is not a good way how to use packages if you would need to update them later.

Comment: sory it' not working for me im run app and
"pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'gcloud' distribution was not found and is required by the application"

Comment: You can try to create an empty `__init__.py` file inside `lib` folder, though I'm not sure it'll work. You see how bad it is? You have a package... which definitely needs another packages(["Requires Distributions"](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gcloud)) which most probably needs another packages. It's not like you have a single independent library here. Just install it with provided instructions and spare yourself troubles now and definitely in future with updating.

Comment: im change python version on 3.5 and its work, but im need 2.7